# Xtext - The type com.google.inject.Inject is not on the classpath

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

I am using the following code in JvmModelInferrer.xtend to generate a Java class

```
@Inject extension JvmTypesBuilder

def dispatch void infer(Model element, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
    acceptor.accept(element.toClass(element.name)) [
        annotations += annotationRef(Inject);
    ]
}
```

When I try to run the whole project, I get the following error.

```
5226 [main] ERROR org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmTypesBuilder  - Error initializing JvmElement
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The type com.google.inject.Inject is not on the classpath.
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmAnnotationReferenceBuilder.annotationRef(JvmAnnotationReferenceBuilder.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmAnnotationReferenceBuilder.annotationRef(JvmAnnotationReferenceBuilder.java:60)
    at org.example.statemodel.jvmmodel.StatemodelJvmModelInferrer.lambda$5(StatemodelJvmModelInferrer.java:60)
    at org.example.statemodel.jvmmodel.StatemodelJvmModelInferrer$$Lambda$8/864303682.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmTypesBuilder.initializeSafely(JvmTypesBuilder.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.jvmmodel.JvmTypesBuilder.toField(JvmTypesBuilder.java:588)
```

I tried adding the corresponding dependency `com.google.inject.source;bundle-version="3.0.0"` to plugin.xml. Still I am getting the same error. How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Check your import statement.  I'm guessing from your question you want to be using the Guice @Inject.  Instead, you've imported the javax one.

Comment: @Aurand - Yeah sorry.. my mistake.. that was a different error when I tried imported the javax one when the Guice one was not working. Updated the correct error log now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that Guice is on the classpath of the project, that contains your DSL file.