# Using Inject in an Xtend based Xtext code generator

Tags: xtext

I am brand new to Xtext and Xtend and am trying to learn Xtext using the Xtext tutorials in the Xtext documentation. I am running on Eclipse Photon under Java 10 with Xtext 2.14. I am starting the extended tutorial and have a problem very early on. Here is the code for my attempt at a code generator:

```
/*
 * generated by Xtext 2.14.0
 */
package net.wiseoldbird.tutorial.domainmodel.generator

import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.AbstractGenerator
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IFileSystemAccess2
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGeneratorContext
import net.wiseoldbird.tutorial.domainmodel.domainmodel.Entity
import com.google.inject.Inject

@Inject extension IQualifiedNameProvider;

class DomainmodelGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {

    override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
        for (e: resource.allContents.toIterable.filter(Entity)) {
        fsa.generateFile(e.fullyQualifiedName.toString("/") + ".java", e.compile)

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my grammar file:

```
grammar net.wiseoldbird.tutorial.domainmodel.Domainmodel
        with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate domainmodel "http://www.wiseoldbird.net/tutorial/domainmodel/Domainmodel"

Domainmodel :
    (elements+=AbstractElement)*;

PackageDeclaration:
    'package' name=QualifiedName '{'
        (elements+=AbstractElement)*
    '}';

AbstractElement:
    PackageDeclaration | Type | Import;

QualifiedName:
    ID ('.' ID)*;

Import:
    'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard;

QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
    QualifiedName '.*'?;

Type:
    DataType | Entity;

DataType:
    'datatype' name=ID;

Entity:
    'entity' name=ID ('extends' superType=[Entity|QualifiedName])? '{'
        (features+=Feature)*
    '}';

Feature:
    (many?='many')? name=ID ':' type=[Type|QualifiedName];
```

My problem is that Eclipse says there is a problem with the @Inject annotation. It says that `Inject cannot be resolved to an annotation type`. This is in an Eclipse Xtext project generated from the instructions in the tutorial.

How do I proceed from here?

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34121018/xtext-the-type-com-google-inject-inject-is-not-on-the-classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can inject only fields and post-init-method/constructor parameters

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource
import org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel.domainmodel.Entity
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.AbstractGenerator
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IFileSystemAccess2
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGeneratorContext
import org.eclipse.xtext.naming.IQualifiedNameProvider

class DomainmodelGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {

    @Inject extension IQualifiedNameProvider

    override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess2 fsa, IGeneratorContext context) {
        for (e : resource.allContents.toIterable.filter(Entity)) {
            fsa.generateFile(e.fullyQualifiedName.toString("/") + ".java", e.compile)

        }
    }

    def compile(Entity e) '''
        package «e.eContainer.fullyQualifiedName»;

        public class «e.name» {
        }
    '''
}
```

Comment: Why did the Quick Fix not suggest the import? The jar was available on the classpath and this was a clean setup in a new Eclipse workspace. I was left wondering what implementation of Inject was intended.

Comment: the problem is: there are no annotations on imports. that is the problem

Comment: In that case, should the tutorial not have a warning or include the import in the tutorial example? After all the tutorial should cater to complete Xtext newbies. I am in the middle of a big learning curve as I am coming back to Java after 15 years of using Python, primarily because of Xtend.

Comment: i dont get your point: if you write `class DomainmodelGenerator extends AbstractGenerator {
 @Inject extension IQualifiedNameProvider
}` then you get quickfixes for all missing imports

Comment: I just added the next line from the tutorial and it gives two errors saying that the fields fullyQualifiedName and compile are undefined for Entity. It seems that my project environment has problems but I have no idea what they might be.

Comment: you still have the extension at the wrong place. see my updated answer

Comment: I added the grammar file to the post.

Comment: The tutorial is confusing then. It seemed to show it as outside of the class declaration.

Comment: no it does not show anything. just the line. feel free to open a ticket at https://github.com/eclipse/xtext to improove the docs